# Creating a 2 dimensional list using java 8 streams

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda

I am trying to create a two dimensional list in java.

My first and preferred method is as so:

```
       List<List<Integer>> seqList = IntStream.range(0, n)
                .mapToObj(ArrayList<Integer>::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, for some reason this method takes too long and I get a timeout.

On the other hand, when I tried to create the two dimensional list using java 7 like so, there was no timeout.

```
        List<List<Integer>> seqList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            seqList.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }
```

I am trying to use as much java-8 streams as possible. Could someone explain to me why my java-8 code is taking too long and what I can do to make it run in the same time complexity as the java-7 code.

Comment: Assuming `n` is large, your first snippet is creating `n` `ArrayList`s, each of which has a different capacity. So you should expect it to take longer. You want to use `.mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<>())` instead.

Comment: Are you saying that  when I call `.mapToObj(ArrayList<Integer>::new)`, the size of each arraylist object created is given an initial size of `n`

Comment: No, rather your code, `.mapToObj(ArrayList<Integer>::new)`, is equivalent to `.mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<>(i))`, which creates an `ArrayList` with a **capacity** of `i`.

Comment: *"I am trying to use as much java-8 as possible"* A regular `for` loop is Java 8 too. It is actually a core part of the language in *all* versions of Java, from version 1 up to version 14 and beyond, and will not be deprecated.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, but I am learning and practising java-8. I already know a for, I want to know more. And I think chaining the calls make it look cool!

Comment: @JacobG. It worked! Thank you alot for your help

Comment: @GilbertS Then say you want to do it with Stream, or with Lambda Expressions, or with Method References. Saying you want to use Java 8 means nothing specific, since all the older features are still there and still very useful.

Comment: @Andreas. OK. I will edit the flags. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative way to do it.

```
        int n = 10;
        List<List<Integer>> seqList =Stream.<List<Integer>>generate(()->new ArrayList<>())
                .limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Whoa. It works. The IDE suggests using method reference like so: `generate(ArrayList::new)`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jacob G I was able to see the problem.

The call `.mapToObj(ArrayList<Integer>::new)` was creating ArrayLists of varying size. It was equivalent to `.mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<Integer>(i))`. Now this means that creating new arraylist objects when `i` is huge take longer hence the timeout. The better code is as follows:

```
  List<List<Integer>> seqList2 = IntStream.range(0, n)
                .mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<Integer>())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

The relative cost of the streaming APIs will be high, even with the correction.  This can be seen by walking through the many steps which are performed.  The complexity is rather quite extraordinary.

The code examples, below, are from the IBM Java SE Runtime Environment version 1.8.

```
// A walkthrough of the operation:
//
// "Create a list of lists by collecting the results of applying the ArrayList
// initializer to the stream of 'int' values ranging from 0 to 10."

static {
    List<List<Integer>> seqList = IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj( ArrayList<Integer>::new )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() );
}

// First step: Create an 'int' Stream.
//
// Roughly, create an 'int' iterator, then wrap that in a 'int' stream.
//
// The iterator is responsible for knowing the initial and final values
// over the range of iteration, and for providing basic iteration.
//
// However, 'mapToObj' is part of the streaming API.  The iterator
// must be put into a stream to access that API.

// The 'int' stream factory method.
//
// Fan out to 'RangeIntSpliterator.init' and to 'StreamSupport.intStream'.
//
// The 'int' stream is created with 'parallel' set to false.

class IntStream {
    public static IntStream range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive) {
        if ( startInclusive >= endExclusive ) {
            return empty();
        } else {
            return StreamSupport.intStream(
                new Streams.RangeIntSpliterator(startInclusive, endExclusive, false),
                false );
        }
    }
}

// The 'int' iterator type.
//
// After setup, 'forEachRemaining' will be used to perform
// the 'int' iteration.

class RangeIntSpliterator implements Spliterator.OfInt {
    protected int from;
    protected final int upTo;
    protected int last;

    RangeIntSpliterator(int from, int upTo, boolean closed) {
        this( from, upTo, (closed ? 1 : 0) );
    }

    void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super Integer> action);
    void forEachRemaining(IntConsumer consumer);
}

// The 'int' stream factory method.
//
// Fan out to 'IntPipeline.Head<>.init'.  'IntPipeline.Head' extends
// 'IntPipeline', which extends 'AbstractPipeline'.
//
// 'IntPipeline.mapToObj' creates an stream of 'ArrayList' instances
// out of the stream of 'int' instances.

class StreamSupport {
    public static IntStream intStream(Spliterator.OfInt spliterator, boolean parallel) {
        return new IntPipeline.Head<>(
            spliterator,
            StreamOpFlag.fromCharacteristics(spliterator),
            parallel );
    }
}

class IntPipeLine.Head<> extends IntPipeline<> {
    Head(Spliterator<Integer> source, int sourceFlags, boolean parallel) {
        super(source, sourceFlags, parallel);
    }
}

class IntPipeline<>
    extends AbstractPipeline<, Integer, IntStream>
    implements IntStream {

    IntPipeline(Spliterator<Integer> source, int sourceFlags, boolean parallel) {
        super(source, sourceFlags, parallel);
    }

    <U> Stream<U> mapToObj(IntFunction<? extends U> mapper);
}

class AbstractPipeline {
    AbstractPipeline(Spliterator<?> source, int sourceFlags, boolean parallel) {
        this.previousStage = null;
        this.sourceSpliterator = source;
        this.sourceStage = this;
        this.sourceOrOpFlags = ( sourceFlags & StreamOpFlag.STREAM_MASK );
        this.combinedFlags = ( (~(sourceOrOpFlags << 1)) & StreamOpFlag.INITIAL_OPS_VALUE );
        this.depth = 0;
        this.parallel = parallel;
    }
}

// Second step: Create a second stream by composing the 'int' stream with the ArrayList
// initializer.
//
// Fan out to 'ReferencePipeline.StatelessOp'. 'StatelessOp' extends 'ReferencePipeline',
// which extends 'AbstractPipeline'.

class IntPipeline {
    @Override
    public final <U> Stream<U> mapToObj(IntFunction<? extends U> mapper) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
        return new ReferencePipeline.StatelessOp<Integer, U>(
            this,
            StreamShape.INT_VALUE,
            (StreamOpFlag.NOT_SORTED | StreamOpFlag.NOT_DISTINCT) ) {

            Sink<Integer> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<U> sink) {
                return new Sink.ChainedInt<U>(sink) {
                    public void accept(int t) {
                        downstream.accept( mapper.apply(t) );
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}

class StatelessOp<E_IN, E_OUT> extends ReferencePipeline<E_IN, E_OUT> {
    StatelessOp(AbstractPipeline<?, E_IN, ?> upstream, StreamShape inputShape, int opFlags) {
        super(upstream, opFlags);

        assert upstream.getOutputShape() == inputShape;
    }

abstract class ReferencePipeline<P_IN, P_OUT>
    extends AbstractPipeline<P_IN, P_OUT, Stream<P_OUT>>
    implements Stream<P_OUT>  {

    ReferencePipeline(Supplier<? extends Spliterator<?>> source, int sourceFlags) {
        super(source, sourceFlags);
    }
}

abstract class AbstractPipeline<E_IN, E_OUT, S extends BaseStream<E_OUT, S>>
    extends PipelineHelper<E_OUT> implements BaseStream<E_OUT, S> {

    AbstractPipeline(AbstractPipeline<?, E_IN, ?> previousStage, int opFlags) {
        if ( previousStage.linkedOrConsumed ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(MSG_STREAM_LINKED);
        }

        previousStage.linkedOrConsumed = true;
        previousStage.nextStage = this;

        this.previousStage = previousStage;
        this.sourceOrOpFlags = opFlags & StreamOpFlag.OP_MASK;
        this.combinedFlags = StreamOpFlag.combineOpFlags(opFlags, previousStage.combinedFlags);
        this.sourceStage = previousStage.sourceStage;
        if ( opIsStateful() ) {
            sourceStage.sourceAnyStateful = true;
        }
        this.depth = previousStage.depth + 1;
    }
}

// Third step: Obtain the collector which is to be used by the 'int' stream.
//
// Note use of 'CH_ID', which marks the collector as an 'identity finisher'.

class Collectors {
    static final Set<Collector.Characteristics> CH_ID =
        Collections.unmodifiableSet( EnumSet.of(Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH) );

    public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
        return new CollectorImpl<>(
            (Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new,
            List::add,
            (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
            CH_ID);
    }
}

class CollectorImpl<T, A, R> implements Collector<T, A, R> {
    private final Supplier<A> supplier;
    private final BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator;
    private final BinaryOperator<A> combiner;
    private final Function<A, R> finisher;
    private final Set<Characteristics> characteristics;

    CollectorImpl(
        Supplier<A> supplier,
        BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator,
        BinaryOperator<A> combiner,
        Function<A,R> finisher,
        Set<Characteristics> characteristics) {

        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.accumulator = accumulator;
        this.combiner = combiner;
        this.finisher = finisher;
        this.characteristics = characteristics;
    }

    CollectorImpl(
        Supplier<A> supplier,
        BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator,
        BinaryOperator<A> combiner,
        Set<Characteristics> characteristics) {

        this(supplier, accumulator, combiner, castingIdentity(), characteristics);
    }
}

// Fourth step: Start collection.
//
// Push the collector through 'ReduceOps.makeRef'.

class ReferencePipeline {
    public final <R, A> R collect(Collector<? super P_OUT, A, R> collector) {
        A container;

        if ( isParallel() &&
             (collector.characteristics().contains(Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT)) &&
             (!isOrdered() ||
              collector.characteristics().contains(Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED))) {

            container = collector.supplier().get();
            BiConsumer<A, ? super P_OUT> accumulator = collector.accumulator();
            forEach(u -> accumulator.accept(container, u));

        } else {
            container = evaluate( ReduceOps.makeRef(collector) );
        }

        return collector.characteristics().contains(Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH)
            ? (R) container
            : collector.finisher().apply(container);
    }
}

class ReduceOps {
    public static <T, I> TerminalOp<T, I> makeRef(Collector<? super T, I, ?> collector) {
        Supplier<I> supplier = Objects.requireNonNull(collector).supplier();
        BiConsumer<I, ? super T> accumulator = collector.accumulator();
        BinaryOperator<I> combiner = collector.combiner();

        class ReducingSink extends Box<I> implements AccumulatingSink<T, I, ReducingSink> {
            public void begin(long size) {
                state = supplier.get();
            }
            public void accept(T t) {
                accumulator.accept(state, t);
            }
            public void combine(ReducingSink other) {
                state = combiner.apply(state, other.state);
            }
        }

        return new ReduceOp<T, I, ReducingSink>(StreamShape.REFERENCE) {
            public ReducingSink makeSink() {
                return new ReducingSink();
            }
        };
    }
}

class ReduceOp<T, R, S extends AccumulatingSink<T, R, S>> implements TerminalOp<T, R> {
    private final StreamShape inputShape;

    ReduceOp(StreamShape shape) {
        inputShape = shape;
    }
}

// Fifth step: Walk into the stream API.

class ReferencePipeline {
    <R> R evaluate(TerminalOp<E_OUT, R> terminalOp) {
        assert ( getOutputShape() == terminalOp.inputShape() );

        if ( linkedOrConsumed ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(MSG_STREAM_LINKED);
        }

        linkedOrConsumed = true;

        return ( isParallel()
           ? terminalOp.evaluateParallel( this, sourceSpliterator( terminalOp.getOpFlags() ) )
           : terminalOp.evaluateSequential( this, sourceSpliterator( terminalOp.getOpFlags() ) ) );
    }
}

class AbstractPipeline {
    Spliterator<E_OUT> sourceStageSpliterator() {
        if ( this != sourceStage ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        if ( linkedOrConsumed ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(MSG_STREAM_LINKED);
        }

        linkedOrConsumed = true;

        if ( sourceStage.sourceSpliterator != null ) {
            Spliterator<E_OUT> s = sourceStage.sourceSpliterator;
            sourceStage.sourceSpliterator = null;
            return s;

        } else if ( sourceStage.sourceSupplier != null ) {
            Spliterator<E_OUT> s = (Spliterator<E_OUT>) sourceStage.sourceSupplier.get();
            sourceStage.sourceSupplier = null;
            return s;

        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(MSG_CONSUMED);
        }
    }
}

class ReduceOp {
    public <P_IN> R evaluateSequential(
        PipelineHelper<T> helper,
        Spliterator<P_IN> spliterator) {

        return helper.wrapAndCopyInto( makeSink(), spliterator ).get();
    }
}

class AbstractPipeline {
    final <P_IN, S extends Sink<E_OUT>> S wrapAndCopyInto(S sink, Spliterator<P_IN> spliterator) {
        copyInto( wrapSink( Objects.requireNonNull(sink) ), spliterator );
        return sink;
    }
}

<P_IN> Sink<P_IN> wrapSink(Sink<E_OUT> sink) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(sink);

    for (  AbstractPipeline p = AbstractPipeline.this; p.depth > 0; p = p.previousStage ) {
        sink = p.opWrapSink( p.previousStage.combinedFlags, sink );
    }
    return (Sink<P_IN>) sink;
}

class StatelessOp {
    Sink<Integer> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<U> sink) {
        return new Sink.ChainedInt<U>(sink) {
            public void accept(int t) {
                downstream.accept( mapper.apply(t) );
            }
        };
    }
}

// Sixth step: Perform the actual iteration and collection.
//
// Ignoring 'begin' and 'end', iteration and collection occurs in the call
// to 'forEachRemaining'.

class AbstractPipeline {
    <P_IN> void copyInto(Sink<P_IN> wrappedSink, Spliterator<P_IN> spliterator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(wrappedSink);

        if ( !StreamOpFlag.SHORT_CIRCUIT.isKnown( getStreamAndOpFlags() ) ) {
            wrappedSink.begin( spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown() );
            spliterator.forEachRemaining(wrappedSink);
            wrappedSink.end();
        } else {
            copyIntoWithCancel(wrappedSink, spliterator);
        }
    }
}

class RangeIntSpliterator implements Spliterator.OfInt {
    void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
        if ( action instanceof IntConsumer ) {
            forEachRemaining((IntConsumer) action);
        } else {
            if ( Tripwire.ENABLED ) {
                Tripwire.trip(getClass(), "{0} calling Spliterator.OfInt.forEachRemaining((IntConsumer) action::accept)");
                forEachRemaining((IntConsumer) action::accept);
            }
        }
    }

    void forEachRemaining(IntConsumer consumer) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(consumer);

        int i = from;
        final int hUpTo = upTo;
        int hLast = last;
        from = upTo;
        last = 0;
        while ( i < hUpTo ) {
            consumer.accept(i++);
        }
        if ( hLast > 0 ) {
            consumer.accept(i);
        }
    }
}

// Seventh step: For each iteration, unwind and perform the mapping and
// collection operations.

class new Sink.ChainedInt<U>(sink) {
    public void accept(int t) {
        downstream.accept( mapper.apply(t) );
    }
}

class ArrayList {
    public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
        // ...
    }
}

class ReducingSink {
    public void accept(T t) {
        accumulator.accept(state, t);
    }
}

class ArrayList {
    public boolean add(E e) {
        // ...
    }
}

// Eigth step: Walking out with the return value.

IntPipeline$4(AbstractPipeline<E_IN,E_OUT,S>).wrapAndCopyInto(S, Spliterator<P_IN>)
  -- returns a 'ReducingSink' instance.
ReduceOps$3(ReduceOps$ReduceOp<T,R,S>).evaluateSequential(PipelineHelper<T>, Spliterator<P_IN>)
  -- returns the 'ArrayList' instance.
IntPipeline$4(AbstractPipeline<E_IN,E_OUT,S>).evaluate(TerminalOp<E_OUT,R>)
  -- returns the 'ArrayList' instance.
IntPipeline$4(ReferencePipeline<P_IN,P_OUT>).collect(Collector<? super P_OUT,A,R>)
  -- returns the 'ArrayList' instance.
Tester.main
```

Comment: Wowww! Ok. I have a lot to ask. First of all, does all that code run with every step in the iteration or does it run only once at the start of the iteration?

Comment: In the class `IntPipeline`, I noticed that you were overriding a method called mapToObj but the class IntPipeline itself does not implement or extend anything so how can it be overriding a method?

Comment: That code is from the java runtime libraries.  I found it by walking through the sample code using the eclipse debugger, and know it only to the extent that I've now walked through it a bit.  I didn't show the entire inheritance each time I put in a class, just the first time.

Comment: Most of the code only runs once.  Iteration occurs within `RangeIntSplitterator.forEachRemaining`  The actual performance, once you get to `forEachRemaining` is not too bad.  The huge constant cost of all of the setup will be significant if the number of iterations is small and the cost of one iteration is not too high.  The constant cost will be less significant if the number or iterations is high or if the cost of an iteration is high.

Comment: `class IntPipeline<E_IN> extends AbstractPipeline<E_IN, Integer, IntStream> implements IntStream` and `IntStream` implements `<U> Stream<U> mapToObj(IntFunction<? extends U> mapper)`.

Comment: I guess streams can be horrible. And I was about to ditch them. But recently I came up with a beautiful line of code that made me think twice. Look at this: `max = Arrays.stream(array).reduce(max, Math::max);` So beautiful. I will use them on one liners like this one.